# Can Ubuntu recognize an external disk drive created by windows xp?

Tags: external-hdd, windows-xp, drive

I have an external Hard Drive Formatted under Windows XP, Can I manage this drive in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Right now the drive is invisible to Ubuntu. How can I use such a drive without reformatting it?

Comment: Ubuntu should have read/write access to a "Windows drive" (usually a FAT32 or NTFS partition) out of the box, no need to install or configure anything. Those partitions should be visible in the file browser, and accessible simply by clicking. If the partition is invisible, you need to provide info beyond general terms. Are the hdds in USB enclosures? Are they connected to the machine? What file system is there?

Comment: Just look to the left bar in Nautilus or the bottom of the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure. It should be installed by default. Assuming there is something wrong just try to  install `ntfs-config`

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g ntfs-config 
gksudo ntfs-config`
```

You should see the external drive in File Explorer (called `nautilus`) at the left side if you open you **Computer Icon** or **Home Folder**

Comment: That should be set p by default.

Comment: anyway if its not set for any reason this will help him.

Comment: That won't help, anyway, without `ntfs-3g`.

Comment: OK I will add it right now