# how to access windows 7 partition files?

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access Windows partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148474/how-to-access-windows-partition)

In previous Ubuntu versions I installed Ubuntu and it always recognized the windows partition.
I installed Ubuntu 12.04.01 LTS and I stoped to see the windows partition.
how to access windows 7 partition files inside Ubuntu? (read and change files)
Thank you for help.
Diogo

Answer (score 0):

In my recent 12.04 LTS install the Windows partitions in the top-left part of the Nautilus program (Is that Ubuntu's version of the Windows Explorer?), so I can click on them.

Windows7 partitions are (normally) NTFS partitions. I think the reply by Kamil [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195068/can-ubuntu-recognize-an-external-disk-drive-created-by-windows-xp) should apply to your situation as well.

If you want to permanently mount them, [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Access-Windows-Files-in-Ubuntu) seems to be able to help you further